# Intellij could not find resource directory

Tags: intellij-idea, log4j2

I had been used log4j2 with the same configuration on my other projects but in this project, Intellij could not find resource directory.
I created resource directory and marked it as Resource Root.

Here is an image that shows my project structures.

[image: Project Structure]

But I got below error.

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.

I had tried to rebuild project and restart IDE, with no success.
I'll be appreciated if somebody helps me.

Comment: You apparently want to follow the Maven/gradle conventions. The resources  directory should thus be src/main/resources, not src/resources. And if you use gradle or Maven and simply import the Maven or gradle project into the IDE, IntelliJ will treat this directory as the resource directory automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr JB Nizet. I moved the resource directory under src/main, and the problem solved.